Value from F expression in Django ORM is not a decimal and Objects has to field named
I have the following classes/models and I'm trying to do bulk update thousands of Recipt objects to have an Item JSON object in the details section
from django.db import models
from schematics import models as schema_models

class Recipt(models.Model):
    id = UUID()
    is_red = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    disputed_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    details = JSONModelField(ReciptDetails)

class ReciptDetails(PickleableModel):
    id = UUID()
    item = schema_types.ModelType(Item)

class Item(schema_models.Model):
    id = schema_types.UUIDType()
    name = schema_types.StringType()
    amount = schema_types.DecimalType()
    description = schema_types.StringType()


When doing:
Recipt.objects.filter(Q(details__item=None), is_red=True).update(details__item=Item({"name": SOMECONST.HAPPY, "amount": F('total_amount')})) 
I get the error:
 *** schematics.exceptions.DataError: {"amount": ["Value 'F(total_amount)' is not decimal."]}
I'm guessing it's because the F expression is inside of the Item class (json object). What is the proper way to get the total_amount value from the Recipt to add to the item json?
Moreover, when I try to set a decimal constant value (to bypass the issue above):
Recipt.objects.filter(Q(details__item=None), is_red=True).update(details__item=Item({"name": SOMECONST.HAPPY, "amount": Decimal("10.00")})) 
I get that:
 django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Recipt has no field named 'details__item'
Any ideas of how to fix these issues? I think it stems from the nesting of JSON objects

I don't know what other package you are using, maybe this? If so that doesn't really seem to be Django compatible or built to work with Django models. Also your usecase doesn't seem like you need any sort of JSONField, some foreign keys should be enough to normalize your data.

I severely simplified the models to make it easier to understand, I definitely need to use jsonfield
